# JSF Outputlabel click event calling bean method

Tags: ajax, jsf, netbeans

Currently I am creating a web menu consists of a collection of `<h:outputLabel>`. It was good since the label can be combined with javascript OnClick event. However when I want to do some server-side processing it become so complicated (at least with my limited knowledge).

I put something like this

```
<h:outputLabel id="Button" onclick="showDiv()">
  <h:outputText value="My Homepage"/>
</h:outputLabel>
```

I tried adding `<f:ajax>`, but man, its not working and I have to put it in `<h:form>`. Is there any elegant and simpler way to do this?

All I want to do is, when user click the label, some bean-method shall be fired up.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways in JSF to get the desired behavior, here is one of them:

Use `<h:commandLink>` and call your backing bean method in the action attribute:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{bean.doSomething()}" value="My Homepage" />
```

`<h:outputLabel>` is used to label some input elements and not to trigger action. And I think you cannot put an `h:outputText` inside an `h:outputLabel`. Please refer to the [Java EE documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/) about the correct way of using it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I know that I could use the commandlink but apparently I am trying to avoid the appearance of a link (underline and blue color).

Comment: You are welcome! Try to use CSS for the formatting of the commandLink.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I used below CSS to remove the underline in the commandLink

```
.borderRemover {
    border: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Are you answering the right question? Are you sitting in the right browser window/tab? This has completely nothing to do with the question currently asked. It's also beyond me why this "answer" got an upvote.

Comment: Sorry I was trying to comment/add on the above answer by @matt but it turn/seem I answered it. I'll be careful next time. thanks.